# Polylang change language automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, function, polylang

Theres any way to change the language of frontpage, automatically with the polylang?
If the user do the login, the page language change automatically.

I'm using this:

```
PLL()->curlang = PLL()->model->get_language( 'fr' );
```

The header and footer change, but the page/content and the url don't change.